# Reverse geocode through Google Maps API inaccurate?

Tags: google-maps-api, reverse-geocoding

I have placed around a 1000 markers in my area through Google My Maps, transformed the KML file to CSV, and now want to transform the coordinates to addresses. I am just testing with the first 5 to test my script (Python) but I am finding that from the 5 test records, only 1 is correct.

For example: 
Coordinate: -33.7909042,151.2603029
Google map: http://maps.google.com/maps?force=canvas&t=m&q=loc:-33.7909042+151.2603029

Clearly you can see the address is Rickard St 42

BUT
When you use the API to geocode the coordinates with: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-33.7909042,151.2603029&key=***APIKEY***

It returns 119 West Street, on the opposite side.

I thought the Google Maps API was really accurate, but the service doesn't reflect the actual map itself. What is going wrong? Is there a better service?

Comment: ... and then if you run the same query several times, you will likely get different results every now and then. From a test I made a few years ago on a short street segment with +- 20 addresses, I always had 20% of error (for different addresses at each run)

Answer (score -2):

I can confirm that using google the [map](https://csv2geo.com/site/map-it?map=batch-geocoding-dGFza19pZD0xNTAwMzE%253D) gets across in to the wrong address.
[image]

Google maps are very good in what they do, but like everything else, sometimes technology fails. I presume their AI that transformed the map marker location got it right by artificially moving the target, where the API did not.

I used same input with out [reverse geocoding tool](https://csv2geo.com) CSV2GEO  and we got the results right on target.
[image]

Here is the result from the reverse geocoding

[image]

Comment: When suggesting your own product to be used in a question that does not mention it please always include a disclosure statement within the body of your question.